# Best approach to a class representing JSON with variable parameters in C#

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I have a webservice in WCF whose operations require requests and responses in JSON format. I know that I can just write C# objects with properties that I want represented in JSON, but my problem is that the JSON parameters may change. For example, my method contract is the following:

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", 
        UriTemplate = "users", 
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    Response PutUserAccount(User user);
```

User's parameters may contain any number of parameters, so an instance of User may be sometimes:

```
{
    "Name" : "John",
    "LastName" : "Doe",
    "Email" : "jdoe@gmail.com",
    "Username" : "jdoe",
    "Gender" : "M"
    "Phone" : "9999999"
}
```

or even:

```
{
    "Name" : "John",
    "LastName" : "Doe",
    "Email" : "jdoe@gmail.com",
    "Username" : "jdoe",
    "FavoriteColor" : "Blue"
}
```

What is the best approach to have an object with a mutable number of properties to represent a JSON document?

**EDIT** This class allowed me to have a flexible JSON representation, since I can't use a `JObject` with WCF (Should I post this as answer?):

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace MyNamespace {
    [Serializable]
    public class Data : ISerializable
    {
        internal Dictionary<string, object> Attributes { get; set; }

        public Data()
        {
            Attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }

        public Data(Dictionary<string, object> data)
        {
            Attributes = data;
        }

        protected Data(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
            : this()
        {
            SerializationInfoEnumerator e = info.GetEnumerator();
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                Attributes[e.Name] = e.Value;
            }
        }

        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            foreach (string key in Attributes.Keys)
            {
                info.AddValue(key, Attributes[key]);
            }
        }

        public void Add(string key, object value)
        {
            Attributes.Add(key, value);
        }

        public object this[string index]
        {
            set { Attributes[index] = value; }
            get
            {
                if (Attributes.ContainsKey(index))
                    return Attributes[index];
                else
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Comment: Create a user object that has all possible properties.

Comment: @I4V I used `User`as an example. There may be unforeseen properties.
@PrestonGuillot I thought about that, but is there a better approach? I might just use Dictionary if I can't find a better one.

Comment: @AntonioJunior `There may be unforeseen properties`; So you expect unforeseen properties to be passed to your `PutUserAccount` method. What do you think to do with them if they are unforeseen? What about if your *unforeseen* object contains other *unforeseen* classes such that `Dictionar<string,string>` wouldn't work?

Comment: @I4V I'll use the Dictionary approach. Sounds good to me. I'll just show the unforeseen properties as they come up. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JObject` class from [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx). You can parse your json to a `JObject` property and manipulate it. `JObject` is more than just a Dictionary.

Comment: Is `JObject` viable as a WCF REST parameter? That would certainly maximize flexibility, while allowing other types and nested objects.

Comment: I still don't use WCF but have found JObject and of course Json.NET so much useful for serialization and deserialization.

Comment: I couldn't user `JObject` as WCF REST parameter. There is an `InvalidDataContractException` exception, because there is a recursive reference inside the class.

Comment: In [Json.NET Documents](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/), it is explained how to handle recursive references. It is under "Serializing and Deserializing JSON" > "Serialization Settings" > ReferenceLoopHandling

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use other JSON types as values for the property, or even child objects, one approach I often use is to define a `[DataContract]` for the incoming object--in your case, `User`--and set the `DataMemberAttribute`s to something along the lines of the following:

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{
    // IsRequired and EmitDefaultValue default to 'true',
    // if not set explicitly
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired=false,EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public Foo MyFoo { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This enforces a specific `User` contract, but allows consumers to pick and choose which optional fields to include. In this snippet, both

```
{ "name":"John" }
```

and

```
{ "name":"Earl", "myFoo":{ "bar":"baz" } }
```

are valid request entities. In the former case, your `user` parameter will have its `MyFoo` property set to `null`.

This would not allow for 'unforeseen' properties, so you will have to decide whether having such a loosely-defined API contract is important in your case.

A hybrid approach might define an optional `Dictionary<string,string> ExtendedProperties` property that consumers could populate with any user-defined data, not already defined in the contract.